# Add multiple Service Principal Name to Keytab file on Windows

Tags: kerberos

What command can I run on windows to add a SPN to a keytab file on Windows? It seems all the documentation I can find is for linux. I want to have multiple SPNs in one keytab file.

Comment: Educate me. What's a keytab file?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator A keytab file is a file containing pairs of Kerberos principals and encrypted keys. It is used for kerberos authentication for sso.